# how to properly sum rows based in an specific date column rank?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, sum

The idea is to get the sum based on the column names that are
between `01/01/2021` and `01/08/2021`:

```
# define rank parameters {start-end}
first_date <- format(Sys.Date(), "01/01/%Y")

actual_date <- format(Sys.Date() %m-% months(1), "01/%m/%Y")


# get the sum of the rows between first_date and actual_date

df$ytd<- rowSums(df[as.character(seq(first_date,
                                       actual_date))])
```

However, when applied the next error arises:

> Error in seq.default(first_date, to_date) :
> 'from' must be a finite number

Expected output is a new column that takes the sum of the rows between the specified rank.

### data

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico"
), `01/01/2021` = c(12, 23, 13, 12), `01/02/2021` = c(12, 23, 
13, 12), `01/03/2021` = c(12, 23, 13, 12), `01/04/2021` = c(12, 
23, 13, 12), `01/05/2021` = c(12, 23, 13, 12), `01/06/2021` = c(12, 
23, 13, 12), `01/07/2021` = c(12, 23, 13, 12), `01/08/2021` = c(12, 
23, 13, 12), `01/09/2021` = c(12, 23, 13, 12), `01/10/2021` = c(12, 
23, 13, 12), `01/11/2021` = c(12, 23, 13, 12), `01/12/2021` = c(12, 
23, 13, 12)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

How could I properly apply a function to get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` and `seq` don't work i.e. `seq` expects a `Date` class whereas the `format` is a `character` class.  Instead, make use of the range operator in `across` or `select`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>% 
    mutate(ytd = rowSums(across(all_of(first_date):all_of(actual_date))))
```

-output

```
> out$ytd
[1]  96 184 104  96
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach using `match` -

```
df$ytd <- rowSums(df[match(first_date, names(df)):match(actual_date, names(df))])
df$ytd
#[1]  96 184 104  96
```